# DirectedEdges -> False not working

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Consider [this graph](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lpkil43eixd57ug/celegansneural.GraphML?dl=0), that I downloaded from the OpenConnectome project.

```
Graph[EdgeList[cElegans], DirectedEdges -> False] // DirectedGraphQ
```

outputs: `True`.

Which makes no sense to me. Is there any logic to this or is this a Mathematica bug?

PS: The same thing happens with `SetProperty[Graph[EdgeList[cElegans]], DirectedEdges -> False] // DirectedGraphQ`

**edit:** The original question was missing the call to `EdgeList`. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Please post only a small graph as your example. You surely don't need 300KB of data to show your point!

Comment: `g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, DirectedEdges -> False]; DirectedGraphQ[g]` yields `False` as does `g //DirectedGraphQ`.

Comment: Smaller example: `imp = Import["http://awesome.cs.jhu.edu/data/static/graphs/worm/c.elegans_neural.male_1.graphml"]; g=Graph[EdgeList[imp][[;;5]],DirectedEdges->False];DirectedGraphQ[g]` gives `True`.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius, in small graphs, DirectedEdges -> False works. In this graphml file it doesn't work, as kglr has also shown. This seems a Mathematica bug.

Comment: a workaround: `Graph[UndirectedEdge@@@EdgeList[imp]]`

Comment: thanks @kglr, I was using Graph[#[[1]] <-> #[[2]] & /@ EdgeList[cElegans]]

Comment: @andandandand, you could also use `Graph[EdgeList[cElegans]/. DirectedEdge->UndirectedEdge]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By documentation, DirectedEdges->False can be used to interpret rules (edges) as undirected edges in Graph. If you want to convert exsiting directed graphs to undirected graphs, you should use UndirectedGraph function.

```
g = UndirectedGraph[cElegans];

DirectedGraphQ[g]
```

> False

Comment: By documentation (and its examples), DirectedEdges->False should create an undirected graph from a directed graph. It's not working with this file.

Comment: @andandandand I see no such examples in the documentation.  What halmir said is correct.  You cannot use `Graph[g, DirectedEdges -> False]` to get an undirected graph is `g` is already a `Graph` expression.  This option controls only how to generate *a new graph* (from a set of edges or otherwise), *but it does not serve for modifying an existing graph*.  There is no bug here.

Comment: @Szabolcs: The 2nd example of https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirectedEdges.html shows Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, DirectedEdges -> False]which works as expected (produces an undirected graph). Graph[EdgeList[cElegans], DirectedEdges -> False] produces a *directed graph* as DirectedGraphQ[Graph[EdgeList[cElegans], DirectedEdges -> False]] will confirm. Please try this, and convince yourself that *this is a bug*.

Comment: @andandandand If you read my comment carefully, you will see that I said: "This option controls only how to generate a new graph (**from a set of edges or otherwise**)".  `{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}` is a set of edges (and not a `Graph` expression), so you can use `DirectedEdges` here.  However, if you already have `g=Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}]` (which is a `Graph` expression, *not a list of edges*), then you *cannot* use `g2 = Graph[g, DirectedEdges -> False]`.  I hope this clears it up for you.

Comment: @Szabolcs, if you read my comment carefully you will see that I wrote "Graph[EdgeList[cElegans], DirectedEdges -> False] produces a directed graph." Notice the call to EdgeList[cElegans]. This produces a *directed graph* in Mathematica 10.2. It should not.

Comment: @andandandand That's because `EdgeList` gives a list of `DirectedEdge` expressions.  `DirectedEdge` is not the same as `Rule`, i.e. `->`.  Note that you can also have mixed graphs in Mathematica.  The `DirectedEdges` option only applies to when the edges are specifies as `Rule`s (which used to be typical before `Graph` was introduced and only `GraphPlot` was available).  However, the main usage of the `DirectedEdges` option is not even this, but functions such as `RandomGraph` or `AdjacencyGraph` which can generate either directed or undirected graphs.

Comment: A `DirectedEdge` is always directed and an `UndirectedEdge` is always undirected, as their names imply. They can be mixed within the same graph. A `Rule` has historically been used for both, so we still have the option to choose what it should represent.

Comment: @Szabolcs. Huh, I see, thanks. I thought that `DirectedEdge` and `UndirectedEdge` were converted to Rules.